# Make RoR nested representable into an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, representable

In using the [representable gem](https://github.com/apotonick/representable), I am looking to nest an object within an array, with that array only having one object. I can't see to figure out how to accomplish this. Any ideas? The reason for this is due to how Google Tag Manager handles enhanced ecommerce tracking.

```ruby
nested 'products' do
  property :name, getter: lambda{|*| name }
  property :id
end
```

Will spit out:

```json
"products": {
  "name" : "Nike Swoosh",
  "id" : 8
}
```

When I want is to come out as:

```json
"products": [ {
  "name" : "Nike Swoosh",
  "id" : 8
} ]
```

Comment: I haven't used this gem but in [documentation](https://github.com/apotonick/representable#collections) they have explained about collections. You might wanna try it.

Comment: Thanks Datt, but the object in question is not a collection, its just a single object so there is nothing to iterate over. Essentially, I just want to wrap the  object in an array, so there is an array of one index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the collection in the representable module. Although you have only a single object, since you want to wrap it in an Array. It technically become a collection with a single object. Then define a getter with that collection name in the parent object. Here is an example:

```
require 'ostruct'
require 'representable'
require 'representable/json'

class Order < Struct.new(:order, :product)

   def products
     [product]
   end  
end

module OrderRepresenter
  include Representable::JSON

  property :name
  collection :products
end


sale = Order.new(name: "An order name", product: {name: "My Product", id: 1})
p sale.extend(SaleRepresenter).to_json
```